# I can't receive 3 Arrays of Strings that I sent with an Intent

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, extras

Main activity

```
     public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] arraynomb = arreglonombreprod.toArray(new String[0]);
            String[] arrayprecios = precioproductoarreglo.toArray(new String[0]);
            String[] arraycant = arreglocantidadprod.toArray(new String[0]);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),claseinventario.class);
            extras.putStringArray("productosx", arraynomb);
            extras.putStringArray("preciosx", arrayprecios);
            extras.putStringArray("cantidadesx", arraycant);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

the other class

public class claseinventario extends Activity {

```
ListViewAdapter adapter;


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String[] prod = extras.getStringArray("productosx");
String[] cant = extras.getStringArray("preciosx");
String[] pre = extras.getStringArray("cantidadesx");



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista);
    final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.viewlista);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, prod, pre, cant);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

logcat:

```
02-22 14:52:58.975: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

02-22 14:52:58.975: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.manuel.supercontrol/com.example.manuel.supercontrol.claseinventario}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 14:52:58.975: E/AndroidRuntime(6623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

02-22 14:52:58.975: E/AndroidRuntime(6623):     at com.example.manuel.supercontrol.claseinventario.(claseinventario.java:15)

line 15# is    - Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: "it always crash" - when? Please post the Logcat errors that show up when it crashes.

Comment: thanks for you suggest Andrew. I have added a link of the logcat at the top of the post.

Comment: Please copy and paste the Logcat text into your question, instead of using an image. Also, what is line #15 in `claseinventario.java`

Comment: move Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); to the onCreate. 
getIntent returns null this early.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String[] arraynomb = arreglonombreprod.toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] arrayprecios = precioproductoarreglo.toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] arraycant = arreglocantidadprod.toArray(new String[0]);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),claseinventario.class);
    intent.putExtra("productosx", arraynomb);
    intent.putExtra("preciosx", arrayprecios);
    intent.putExtra("cantidadesx", arraycant);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And to retrieve them:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String[] prod = intent.getExtra("productosx");
String[] cant = intent.getExtra("preciosx");
String[] pre = intent.getExtra("cantidadesx");
```

To make the code even cleaner, you should consider using standard Java class naming conventions (uppercase Class names, for example), and constant values for the `Extra` names, but the code above should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `getApplicationContext()` in Intent,Use `Activity.this`

if the extras you are passing are arraylist,you can directly pass the arraylist as

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key",arraylist here);
```

and in the other activity you have to check for nullpointer on extras or the specific key

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null){
  if(bundle.containsKey("key)){
    //....extract extra here
  }
}
```